# Получить данные обработка php в том виде в котором нужно

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

как правильно составить обработчик `php` что бы на выходе получить данные в виде:

```
  var Items = [
    {
      value: "Наклейки лист А3 ONE IND",
      label: "Наклейки лист А3 ONE IND",
      desc: "",
      icon: "2301_nakleyki-list-a3-one-ind.jpg"
    },
    {
      value: "Наклейки лист А4 FOX",
      label: "Наклейки лист А4 FOX",
      desc: "",
      icon: "2325_nakleyki-list-a4-fox.jpg"
    },
    {
      value: "Наклейки лист А4 RokStar RED",
      label: "Наклейки лист А4 RokStar RED",
      desc: "",
      icon: "2324_nakleyki-list-a4-rokstar-red.jpg"
    }
  ];
```

имеется таблица с двумя столбцами:

[image: table]

вот сам обработчик:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","***","***","***") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $sql = "SELECT prefix_shop.name1 AS name, prefix_images.name AS img FROM prefix_shop JOIN prefix_images ON (prefix_shop.id = prefix_images.element_id) WHERE prefix_images.module_name like 'shop'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $all_items = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $all_items[] = $row['name'];
        $all_items[] = $row['img'];
    }
    echo json_encode($all_items);
?>
```

сей час прилетает `json` с массивом только `name` и `img` но через запятую, меня это конечно же не устраивает. Как правильно будет составить обработчик что бы он причесал данные так как мне нужно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо иначе прокручиваться через результат запроса.

```
$all_items = Array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $all_items[] = Array(
        "value"=>$row['name'],
        "label"=>$row['name'],
        "icon"=>$row['img']
    );
}
echo json_encode($all_items);
```

Поскольку `desc` у вас в примере пустой - его можно просто не создавать...

Comment: то что нужно, 5 минуток жду и потверждаю

Answer (score 1):

Никогда не понимал идею сначала в запросе давать одно имя поля, а потом устраивать кучу писанины только для того чтобы снова переименовать.

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","***","***","***");

$sql = "SELECT s.name1 value, i.name icon FROM prefix_shop s
        JOIN prefix_images i ON s.id = i.element_id 
        WHERE i.module_name = 'shop'";
echo json_encode($mysqli->query($sql)->fetch_all());
```